# java.net.ProtocolException: Cannot write output after reading input

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet, struts

I am trying to send the object from applet to struts action class
using object output stream but it gives me a exception `java.net.ProtocolException`: Cannot write output after reading input.

I created a new instance of URLConnection to giving specific url
and tried to write object in url to send the struts action class from applet

### i am calling this method on save button click of applet

public  saveDesign()
    {

```
    try
    {

        HttpURLConnection  urlConnection = getServletConnection(CallServletConnection.SAVE_DESIGN, null);
        // Pragma = no-cache; should be null

        if(urlConnection != null && urlConnection.getHeaderFields().get("Pragma") != null)
            return false;





OutputStream outstream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();//Exception occur here

        ObjectOutputStream objectoutstream = new ObjectOutputStream(outstream);

        objectoutstream.writeObject("abc");
        objectoutstream.flush();
        objectoutstream.close(); 
        System.out.println("vctObjectDetails is write ");


    }
     catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } 
     catch(ConnectException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
     } 
     catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

but it doesn't work. 
Please gives me some tips if anyone knows how to handle this exception.

Comment: Post full code. You must be doing something wrong somewhere.....

Comment: added the full code plz tell me if anything is wrong.

Comment: @YuvRAJ still cant find the full code.

Comment: What's in this method? getServletConnection

Comment: Thanks For Quick Reply.I got the solution.Problem was my content-type - set it to "text".

Comment: Seriously that was it? Interesting I don't know any reason for that to be...

Answer (score 2):

It all has to do with the lifecycle of an HTTP request (which is what HttpURLConnection abstracts) - once the request has been sent, you cannot modify it any further - in case you have more data to send, you just make another one.
What is happening underneath is that once you call `getHeaderFields()` (the response header fields), the 'HttpURLConnection' sends the request and makes the response available.

I don't know what is in 'getServletConnection()', but you could try using ['doOutput()'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#doOutput) and not reading from the response, until you have finished writing to the request.

Comment: the getServletConnection() is simple method which gives me a servlet path, no issues with that. anyway i got the solution thanks for reply
just need to set content type to "text"
and add a getInputStream in that code then it works fine.